# Only output errors / warnings when compile kernel?

Tags: kernel, make, gcc

When you compile kernel you normally see lines like

`CC XX.o` or `LD XX`

So, can I skip these messages? Only output errors or warnings generated by gcc

Comment: How about `make > /dev/null`? Why would you want to do that actually?

Comment: @peterph to filter out "normal" messages

Comment: Yes, warnings/errors go to `stderr`. Or (in bash) `make 2>&1 1>stdout.log | tee stderr.log` - you'll get both logged, only `stderr` will be displayed.

Comment: @peterph But if the `CC ...` line got lost, you won't be able to figure out where the message comes from.

Comment: compilers usually include the file name in the warning/error message.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `make -s` works.

That would make the whole procedure "silent".